# OSX Error when signing Adobe AIR hardened Runtime

Tags: macos, air, adobe, notarize, hardening

I am having trouble with my Mac Adobe AIR app only after signing with hardening the runtime.
If I don't harden the runtime, it works fine.
The program may start but will eventually generate a memory fault.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to add the following to the entitlements file:

```
<key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
<true/>
```

I hope this helps others.

Comment: This could potentially really help others if you post the error messages.

Comment: This is necessary to prevent random memory faults during program start or execution.

Comment: Of course.  Posting the error messages would allow more people to search those messages and find your answer.